# Equal index height for inline math

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I used `$\mathbf{h}_x\mathbf{h}_x^T$` in the latex and I found that the `x` in the first term is stated upper than the 2nd term. How can I set equal index height for both terms?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thank you, Mico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an empty superscript term, `^{}`, forces down the position of the subscript `x` term -- to the location it occupies in `\mathbf{h}_x^T`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{h}_x \mathbf{h}_x^{} \mathbf{h}_x^T$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, Thanks.